# Accidentally clicked "Hide all messages from x" while trying to debug a react app

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

As the title says, I accidentally clicked "Hide messages from {x}", though I don't know what x was, specifically. I was getting a React warning/error

"Warning: MyForm is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component"

I accidentally right clicked on that message and hid it(it's the top option on right click). Below is what that looked like(but with a different item that I'm definitely not clicking).

[image]

I've been through all the "how to unhide chrome console quests/answers I can find, and none of them have worked to get this message back.

I've tried:

- clicking the "Default Levels drop down" and selecting every single option there.
- tried every combination of those yellow check boxes
- tried hitting F1 clicking "Restore defaults and reload"
- clearing the text in the "Filtered" input box
- restarted server
- restarted chrome

It appears there used to be a right click option to "unhide all", but that was removed by chrome in 2018

As you can see there is still that 1 hidden (but crucial) React message, and once you accidentally hide it, it seems there is no way to get it back.

This is pretty much a showstopper for me, since it means I can't see React errors at all in Chrome. Please help!

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 2):

You just have to clear the filter section in the chrome console (see image attached). This should bring you back to square one.

[image: filtered chrome console]

[image: unfiltered]